# How can a CosmosDb SQL query projection be done so that the structure of the object is maintained?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I want to project, while maintaining the structure of the object. The below is an example, the solution should work for an arbitrary json schema.

```
SELECT c["user"]["firstname"] from c
```

Returns:

```
{
    "firstname": "Foo"
}
```

Instead, I want it to return

```
{
    "user": {
        "firstname": "Foo"
    }
}
```

In addition, if the property does not actually exist on the object, I want the property to not be returned.

This rules out doing something like this because the property "user" will still be populated even if it does not exist on the object.

```
SELECT VALUE {"user": { "firstname": c["user"]["firstname"] }} from c
```

The only solution I am aware of is using an alias, and then "unflattening" the results. But that requires having a special character (CosmosDb only allows '_') as a delimiter for nested properties, which I want to avoid. Example:

```
SELECT c["user"]["firstname"] as user_firstname from c
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT {"username": c.user.firstname} AS user from c WHERE IS_DEFINED(c.user.firstname)
```

In the above query, the projection `{"username": c.user.firstname} AS user` creates the desired output structure and `IS_DEFINED()` method filters out the objects without property `c.user.username`.

Comment: This is a very specific solution. I am looking for a generic solution, that works with an arbitrary object schema. I also do not want to use WHERE clause because that adds additional query cost.

Comment: The projection in answer can be modified and applied to similar situations. Is there any specific response format you are looking to solve? And I assume filtering would add additional cost to the query, it would be interesting if there is any way filtering can be done without adding cost.

Comment: I don't think your filter clause works. What if I am selecting multiple properties, where some properties exist and others don't on the object. Your filter clause would remove the object from the results entirely.